# Handsontable custom header

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Good day everyone.

I have a task: make custom header, well, header itself is made, but i got following trouble:

i have custom html string for header ie :

```
var str = "
<tr><th colspan='2'>global</th><tr>
<tr><th><img src='generateonflypath' /></th><th><img src='generateonflypath' /></th><tr>
"
```

And when i apply it like this:

```
$hotContainer.handsontable({
    afterRender: function () {$('.htCore > thead').html(str);}
});
```

My HOT height remains same and lowest rows are unseen until i click on any cell.
How to fix this issue? ('beforerender' event works even worse)

Thanks for Your time!

Comment: have not used HOT, but if there is a way to refresh/reload the table , try doing that after adding header!

Comment: it has only .render method, but i will get eternal loop then. I can't figure out what events fired after selecting cell (

Comment: temporary solution is to make table header of maximum possible height, but if height is not predefined it can cause some ugly layout.

Comment: that event is `afterSelection` !

Comment: try `minSpareRows: 2`   http://jsfiddle.net/j8g7P/

Comment: thx, but i have strict max rows..

Comment: still works if you comment out the minSpareRows line in @rps 's jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of rough experiments I've ended with this solution:

```
$container.handsontable({
    ...options...
    afterRender: function () { //add custom header
          $('.htCore > thead').html(jsonObj.Headers);
          //add container resize event handler for images that loaded in header
          $('.htCore > thead img').load(function(){
                 $('.wtHider').height($('.htCore').height()+10);
          });   
    } 
});
```

The idea behind this, is to change height of HOT's main table container.
I think others can do just same with other events, not only load img, but change text etc...

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use the build in renderers now in > 2.0 versions.

```
//options
columnHeads: (index, element) => {
  // return html
  return `<a href="/">Link</a>`;
}
```